# Django Administration: Combine admin application model

Tags: django, django-admin

I am using all auth and created another model ambassadors. I have currently the issue that Django Administration shows me these both models now in two different boxes. Does anyone know how to combine these?

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9kvG.png)

My goal is to have

Accounts:

1. Email-Addresses
2. Ambassdadors

Comment: please post your URLs and your admin.py

Answer (score 0):

Use django plugin. It Reorder apps in admin index - this will allow you to position most used apps in top of the page, instead of listing apps alphabetically.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-modeladmin-reorder